# Subdomain keeps pointing to main domain and 404

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm having an issue where I have a main domain website (e.g. **example.com** and **subdomain.example.com**). example.com has a WordPress installation, while the subdomain has a php application. I can access WordPress no issue, but when I go to **subdomain.example.com** it just shows WordPress, and when I go to open **subdomain.example.com/index.html** it just returns a 404.

I have the server running on a pretty clean Ubuntu Server 22.04, running Apache2, MariaDB, and php. My DNS is hosted via Cloudflare.I have my DNS settings correct with A names, etc. I've not really done a whole lot apart from just getting the basics going

example.com vhost file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
 
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/020-wpvhost.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/020-wpvhost.access.log combined
 
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well\-known/acme\-challenge/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
 
</VirtualHost>
 
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
 
    # curl https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/ffdhe2048.txt >> /path/to/signed_cert_and_intermediate_certs_and_dhparams
    SSLCertificateFile      /etc/apache2/ssl/example.com.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/apache2/ssl/example.com.key
 
    # enable HTTP/2, if available
    Protocols h2 http/1.1
 
    # HTTP Strict Transport Security (mod_headers is required) (63072000 seconds)
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000"
 
</VirtualHost>
 
# intermediate configuration
SSLProtocol             all -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
SSLCipherSuite          ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AE>SSLHonorCipherOrder     off
SSLSessionTickets       off
 
SSLUseStapling On
SSLStaplingCache "shmcb:logs/ssl_stapling(32768)"
```

subdomain.example.com vhost file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 
    ServerName subdomain.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/dash.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/dash.access.log combined
 
    <Directory /var/www/mysite/public>
           Options FollowSymLinks
            ReWriteEngine On
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
 
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well\-known/acme\-challenge/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
 
</VirtualHost>
 
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
 
    # curl https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/ffdhe2048.txt >> /path/to/signed_cert_and_intermediate_certs_and_dhparams
    SSLCertificateFile      /etc/apache2/ssl/example.com.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/apache2/ssl/example.com.key
 
    # enable HTTP/2, if available
    Protocols h2 http/1.1
 
    # HTTP Strict Transport Security (mod_headers is required) (63072000 seconds)
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000"
</VirtualHost>
 
# intermediate configuration
SSLProtocol             all -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
SSLCipherSuite          ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AE>SSLHonorCipherOrder     off
SSLSessionTickets       off
 
SSLUseStapling On
SSLStaplingCache "shmcb:logs/ssl_stapling(32768)"
```

I can't work out where I have gone wrong.

Comment: Is the config file actually included? Are you accessing the server via HTTP? There is no VirtualHost definition for HTTPS.

Comment: No, I am accessing via HTTPS. I didn't copy the whole vhost file as is didn't format correctly on here, and was very long. But basically I used the Mozilla SSL Config Generator, if that can shed some light?

Comment: If you use https show the https config. Don't worry about the format, someone will fix it for you.

Comment: If it helps, I installed WordPress first before anything else. I created the vhost file using the Mozilla SSL Config Generator, then created the second vhost for my subdomain.

Comment: I have edited the post with Pastebin links to my vhosts file (it wouldn't format correctly on here for some reason)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like, in your SSL `vhost` sections, you have no `ServerName`, `ServerAlias` or `DocumentRoot` directives. If your web sites are configured to redirect to SSL, you'll only ever get your default web site once you redirect to SSL, which apparently is your `example.com` site.